# Android NO Image written on the specified MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT URI

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-camera-intent, image-capture

In my application `ImageTakerActivity` creates `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent to capture image.

I specified the following `URI` as `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`. So its expected that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will write the taken photo to the corresponding file represented in the URI.

```
                 /******** ImageTakerActivity *********/

private void captureImage()
{
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();

    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FULL_SCREEN, true);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE);
    }
}

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri()
{
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}


private File getOutputMediaFile()
{
    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    //Deleting previous Images
    if(mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        DeleteRecursive(mediaStorageDir);
    }

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
        {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create " + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

In `ActivityResult` I did the following to retrieve the saved image:

```
private void decodeImageStream()
{
    InputStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        //this fileUri was passed to the takePictureIntent
        stream =  getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);

        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the time expected image is successfully decoded in `image` variable.

But sometimes after taking the picture when i tap `OK`, whole screen does a quick rotation and becomes black. After returning to `onActivityResult` of `ImageTakerActivity`, I get nothing in the `image` variable! Also there is no Exception on `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` too.

I have tried reading various articles available, but I don't know how to resolve the issue. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: "So its expected that ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE will write the taken photo to the corresponding file represented in the URI" -- there are many camera apps. Some will have bugs. "I don't know how to resolve the issue" -- most likely, there is little that you can do. I would focus your debugging efforts on `fileUri`, to see if it is a valid value and see if there is a photo in that location.

Comment: there is no photo written in the fileLocation. I am just trying to understand why?! And this behavior is random.

Comment: Assuming that you are reliably passing the file location via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then presumably there is a bug in the camera app.

Comment: This is very much an issue.  Did you perhaps find a solution other than ditching it and using to stock uri that is being returned?